# What assumptions are needed for $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{a} f(x)+f(-x)\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, substitution

This might seem like a strange question, but I was wondering what assumptions is needed for

$\displaystyle \hspace{1cm}\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{a} f(x)+f(-x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

I am *not* asking for under which assumptions the integral *exists/converges* only, under which assumptions the equality holds.

Obviously for the integral to converge we need 
$f$ to be integrable in some form, however is that needed just for the equality to hold.

Similarly does $a$ need to be real, what restrictions is needed upon $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you are talking about Riemann integrals.

- If $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[-a,a]$, then the equality holds, as user289143 showed it.
- If $f$ is not Riemann-intehrable, then the LHS is meaningless, but the RHS can still be zero, because if $f$ is odd, then $f(x)+f(-x)=0$, and it's integrable.
- If $f$ is improper Riemann-integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, and $a=\infty$,  the equality still holds, you just need to take the limit as $a \to +\infty$
- If $f$ is not improper Riemann-integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, the LHS is meaningless, but the RHS can be zero, if $f$ is odd.
- If $f$ is unbounded, improper Riemann-integrable on $[-a, a]$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$, then the equality still holds. We can assume that there is only one singularity on $[-a, a]$, because if there were more, we would be able to split it into smaller intervals, with only $1$ singularity in each. So let's assume that the singularity is at $b \in (0, a)$ (the edge-case, i.e. $b=a$ is the same, with only one limit). Then the LHS is, by definition:
  $$\lim_{q \to b-0}\int_{-a}^b f + \lim_{p \to b+0} \int_b^a f$$
  And the RHS is:
  $$\lim_{q \to b-0}\int_{0}^b f(x)+f(-x) \mathrm{d}x + \lim_{p \to b+0} \int_b^a f(x) + f(-x) \mathrm{d}x$$
  And you can just split up the integral in the LHS to the intervals $[-a, 0]$ and $[0, q]$, because the limit exists, and pull out the $[-a, 0]$ part. In the RHS, you can use the additivity of the integral to separate the integral of $f(-x)$ (and the existence of the limits), and after a substitution, note that the two sides are the same.
- If $f$ is unbounded, not improper Riemann-integrable on $[-a, a]$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$, then the LHS is meaningless, but the RHS can be zero, if $f$ is odd.

Comment: A simple example for the last case is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. And one can deal with these cases by means of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: @b00nheT That function is not improper Riemann-integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. The Cauchy PV integral is a different thing. Of course, in PV sense, the equality holds.

Comment: The case left: if unounded $f$ is improper Riemann-integrable on $[-a,a]$, and $a<\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar Is the new part good? I tried to give just a sketch of the calculation.

Comment: This was a perfect answer! I have quite a few more similar cases and results, thus I wanted to get an idea on which assumptions are necessary just for the equality to hold.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=\int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx+\int_0^a f(x)dx$, so you're asking when
$$
\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx=\int_0^af(-x)dx
$$
and this is trivially true because with the substitution $u=-x$, we have
$$
\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx=\int_{a}^0f(u)du=\int_{a}^0f(-x)(-dx)=-\int_a^0f(-x)dx=\int_0^af(-x)dx
$$